# Cannot be resolved or is not a field facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am getting these errors in my code for a Facebook Login.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
post_image cannot be resolved or is not a field FBActivity.java /Login/src/com/test/finalproject    line 63 Java Problem
update_status cannot be resolved or is not a field  FBActivity.java /Login/src/com/test/finalproject    line 72 Java Problem
user_name cannot be resolved or is not a field  FBActivity.java /Login/src/com/test/finalproject    line 50 Java Problem
fb_login_button cannot be resolved or is not a field    FBActivity.java /Login/src/com/test/finalproject    line 51 Java Problem

Facebook activity.

```
package com.test.finalproject;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback;

public class FBActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private LoginButton loginBtn;
private Button postImageBtn;
private Button updateStatusBtn;

private TextView userName;

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

private static String message = "Sample status posted from android app";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fb_login);

    userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
            if (user != null) {
                userName.setText("Hello, " + user.getName());
            } else {
                userName.setText("You are not logged");
            }
        }
    });

    postImageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post_image);
    postImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            postImage();
        }
    });

    updateStatusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_status);
    updateStatusBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    buttonsEnabled(false);
}

private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            buttonsEnabled(true);
            Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session opened");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            buttonsEnabled(false);
            Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session closed");
        }
    }
};

public void buttonsEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    postImageBtn.setEnabled(isEnabled);
    updateStatusBtn.setEnabled(isEnabled);
}

public void postImage() {
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Request uploadRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                Session.getActiveSession(), img, new Request.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Toast.makeText(FBActivity.this,
                                "Photo uploaded successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        uploadRequest.executeAsync();
    } else {
        requestPermissions();
    }
}

public void postStatusMessage() {
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(
                Session.getActiveSession(), message,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        if (response.getError() == null)
                            Toast.makeText(FBActivity.this,
                                    "Status updated successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        request.executeAsync();
    } else {
        requestPermissions();
    }
}

public boolean checkPermissions() {
    Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (s != null) {
        return s.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    } else
        return false;
}

public void requestPermissions() {
    Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (s != null)
        s.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                this, PERMISSIONS));
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    buttonsEnabled(Session.getActiveSession().isOpened());
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
}
```

}

And My XML layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp" >

<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    facebook:confirm_logout="false"
    facebook:fetch_user_info="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/update_status"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/update_status" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/post_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/post_image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Help Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Add import statement for `R`. Currently it's probably resolved as `android.R` but it should be `your.package.name.R`. I think that's why user_name cannot be resolved even if it is declared in XML.

Comment: that solved the user_name but there is still update_status and post_image errors, any idea ?

Comment: Did you add `import your.package.name.R;` statement? Or only apply it to user_name?

Comment: I imported it to the project

Comment: Well I've copied your code add `import com.test.finalproject.R;` statement to Facebook Activity file and all errors disappeared. Double-check that.

Comment: I put it in, cleaned the project now my R.java file is deleted and I have 53 errors :(

Comment: Don't get upset :) Most of the time start errors generate later errors and we have an occurrence of accumulation. If you noticed lack of R.java file that means you have some errors in XML files. And most of your errors are propably a consequence of lack of that file. So check XML files for bugs and all should be good :)